# unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"' while trying to set time using ssh

Tags: linux, perl, ssh

I have a perl script that runs commands on some PCs remotely via SSH. So I want to set the time on all pcs to be the same. The PCs are a linux based system and the perl script uses another .txt file that has the commands to execute. But when I run the perl script, I got the following error :

```
Command = date --set "27 SEP 2012 19

sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

The perl script is working fine because I tried another command and it gives the results.
So what could cause this error.

The perl code is :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

open (MYFILE,'HostIPWithCmd.txt');
$i=0;
 @IPs=<MYFILE>;
 foreach (@IPs) {
chomp;
($EthIP,$Cmd)= split(":");
 if($EthIP!=~ ("#"))
 {
    push(@hostIP,$EthIP);
    push(@destCmd,$Cmd);

 }

 else
 {
   push(@hostIP,"$EthIP");
   push(@destCmd,$Cmd);
 }
}

$i=0;

foreach my $host (@hostIP)
{
   if($host !=~ ("#"))
   {

      my @cmds= split(/,/,$destCmd[$i]);
      print "\n\nCommands For $host = $destCmd[$i]\n";


   foreach my $command (@cmds)
             {
 print "\n*************************************";
 print "\nCommand = $command \n\n";
 system("ssh -o ConnectTimeout=10 $host $command");

         }

  print "\n***** End Of Host : $host  *****\n";
  print "************************************************************\n\n";
      }

 $i++;
}
```

and the HostIPWithCmd.txt

```
   10.20.146.97:date --set "27 SEP 2012 19:00:00"
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try it with single quotes around the date/time, i.e. `date --set '27 SEP 2012 19:00:00'`

Comment: Your PCs are Linux --- Configure NTP on them!!!

Comment: There is no `!=~` operator, you want `!~`. `("#")` should be `/#/`, and there is no difference between `$EthIP` and `"$EthIP"`.

Comment: @Paul R I try it now and I got the same error: sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''

@TLP the script is working perfect and I try the command for example ls and I got the result but the problem seems with the command itself not with the script

Answer (score 4):

It's quite simple. It's because you have colons otherwhere in your string, which causes the end of your string to disappear. The statement:

```
($EthIP,$Cmd)= split(":");
```

with the input:

```
10.20.146.97:date --set "27 SEP 2012 19:00:00"
```

Will yield:

```
$EthIP = '10.20.146.97';
$Cmd   = 'date --set "27 SEP 2012 19';
```

And the rest of the split list (which is discarded) would be:

```
@rest = ("00", "00");
```

Because you split on colon `:`. A simple fix would be to have a limit:

```
($EthIP,$Cmd)= split(/:/, $_, 2);  # max 2 fields
```

### ---

However, it is doubtful that your code will work even with this fix. There are quite a few serious errors in your code. From top to bottom:

- You do not use `use strict; use warnings;` This is a **major** mistake, since it will allow you to have silent warnings and typos in your code (See below for examples). Never write perl code without these two pragmas.
- You use an `open` statement without checking the return value, e.g. `open MYFILE, 'HostwithIP.txt' or die $!`. Not checking the return value will allow the open to fail silently, causing all sorts of troubles. Not using `warnings` will not warn you that you are reading from a closed file handle, and you will be sitting there scratching your head all day long before you figure it out.
- You use the two argument open with a global file handle. You should use an explicit open mode and a lexical file handle. E.g. `open my $fh, "<", 'HostIPWithCmd.txt" or die $!`.
- You are using `foreach (@IP)` instead of simply iterating over the file handle, e.g. `while (<MYFILE>)`
- `split` uses a regex, not a string. It will convert a string to a regex, but its better to do it right from the start. `split /#/`.
- There is no `!=~` operator. It will be interpreted as `$foo != ~ $bar`, or in other words, a numerical inequality check between `$foo` and the bitwise negation of `$bar`. The operator you want is `!~`. This particular thing will break your code into so many little pieces, especially when you don't use `warnings`, and the error is silent. So no, as you said in your comment, your script is **not** working perfectly, it is horribly broken. You just don't see it because you don't use `warnings`.
- Your if-else statement is completely redundant, because the same thing happens in both if and else clause. There is no difference between `$EthIP` and `"$EthIP"`. Both are exactly identical. This is perhaps the reason you think your code is working.

Also, when using `system`, backticks or `qx()` it is always a good idea to consider other ways to solve the problem. There are modules that can handle this much better for you than `system`.